# Can I add customized control to ribbon?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, customization, ribbon-control

Is there a way to add a customized lookupedit to DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonControl? In my RibbonPageGroup, I can right click to add controls including LookUpEdit. But if I want to add my customized control to RibbonPageGroup, is it allowed and how to do that? I search online but didn't find much useful information about it. Thanks! I am working on WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be only done if this control is derived from the DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit class.  Also, you should register the corresponding RepositoryItem as it is described in the [How to register a custom editor for use in the XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=A1237) article.